# problem deleting all null values from a column in sql in python and sql

Tags: python, sql

i have a table that holds reviews for various items and some of the entries are null because nothing could be found from it. so i tried deleting them with this in python but i get the error " Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'NULL' ".

[image of test code]

[image: 1]

[image of table. i need help deleting all null columns in the reviews column][image: 2]

Comment: What about `IS NULL` instead of `.. = 'NULL'`?

Comment: avoid pasting screenshots

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL code compares the value to the string `'NULL'` instead of the value `NULL`.
Try `DELETE FROM item_info WHERE Reviews_of_item IS NULL`

Comment: thanks it was soo stupid of me not to see that

Comment: Happens to all of us!

Answer (score 0):

When you say  = Null it means `NULL` is just like any other string for example 'car'.
Or it is also equal to this:

```
select 
* , 
'NULL' AS string_null 
from item_info
```

However, what you are interested in is removing rows that don't have any value which is the dafault nature `NULL`. To do that use:

```
DELETE FROM item_info WHERE Reviews_of_item IS NULL
```